# Accessing a certain element in an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have an array of products. I would like to put one more product to the array if it doesnt already exist. And get the product inside of the array and increase the item count by 1 if it is already in the array. I have the following code. It doesn`t seem to work. BTW i am new to php, sorry if this is a simple question.

```
if(!in_array($product, $sc->products)){
   array_push($sc->products,$product);
   }else{
   $key = array_search($product, $sc->products);
   $sc->products[$key]->productCounter++;
}
```

My shoppingCart class

```
class shoppingChart extends Model
{
public $products;

function __construct() {
   $this->products = Array();
  }

public function ItemCount(){
   return count($this->products);

}
}
```

And My Product class

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public $productCounter=0;

    public function image(){ 
       return $this->hasOne('App\Image');
    }
}
```

Comment: Which bit does not work?

Comment: $sc->products[$key]->productCounter++; the dollar sign is wrong in that @apokryfos. I am trying to get the product and increase it`s counter by 1

Comment: `$sc->products` is array of objects I suppose. `in_array` will always be false.

Comment: so i can not search for an object in an array of objects using in_array? @u_mulder

Comment: No, you cannot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is because you are searching based on an object here:

```
array_search($product, $sc->products);
in_array($product, $sc->products);
```

Consider giving each product and `id` or some kind of `unique identifier` to use as a comparison.

You could use a functions like the following to add to the products quantity or to return a product based on its id:

```
function findProductById($id){

    // LOOP LIST OF PRODUCTS
    foreach ( $products as $product ) {

        // LOOK FOR MATCHING ID
        if ( $id == $product->id ) {

            // RETURN FOUND PRODUCT
            return $product;

        }

    }

    // RETURN FALSE (FAILED TO FIND PRODUCT)    
    return false;

}


function addToQuantityOfProduct($id){

    // GET PRODUCT FROM ID
    $foundProduct = findProductById($id);

    // CHECK IF PRODUCT FOUND
    if($foundProduct !== false){

        // ADD TO PRODUCT COUNTER
        $foundProduct->productCounter++;

        // RETURN TRUE (SUCCESSFULLY UPDATED QUANTITY)
        return true;

    }else{

        // RETURN FALSE (FAILED TO FIND PRODUCT)    
        return false;

    }

}
```